# How can I create an n-dimensional Hadamard transform in Q#?

Tags: q#

I would like to create a n-dimensional Hadamard transform in Q# with n in set of even integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to implement $H^\otimes$ (i.e., applying the Hadamard transform to each of the $n$ qubits), you can use library operation [ApplyToEach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.applytoeach):

```
using (register = Qubit[n]) {
    ApplyToEach(H, register);
}
```

---

If you are indeed looking for quantum Fourier transform, as the other answer suggests, the Q# library operation that implements it is [ApplyQuantumFourierTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.applyquantumfouriertransform).

Comment: thank you! if I have a register like |000>, |111> I would need to use quantum fourier transform?

Comment: That really depends on what you want to do with it. Quantum Fourier transform will prepare a superposition of basis states with complex amplitudes, applying an H gate - a superposition of basis states with amplitudes +1 and -1, depending on the input state.

Answer (score 1):

The higher order analog of Hadamard Transform is the Quantum Fourier Transform.
You can learn more about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform).

Comment: I would rather said that Hadamard $n$ dimensional transform is equivalent to application of QFT on state $|0\rangle ^ {\otimes n}$.